# How to delete ContentDocumentLink records massive

Tags: delete, contentdocument

I want to free some space in salesforce related to Chatter Files or Files, I though all records are stores in ContentDocument object, but when I delete records from this object, the file storage still almost 100% or more. So I saw into the ContentDocumentLink if I delete the record from there my storage start to free space.

My question is how can I export all ContentDocumentLink records, now I'm able to export or query only one by one, for example :

```
SELECT ContentDocumentId,Id FROM ContentDocumentLink where ContentDocumentId='069A0000001WgPy'
```

If I don't use a filter this message appear:

[image]

There's a way to export all records or simply delete all of them?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Salesforce has a knowledge article describing the process of Deleting or Archiving items stored in Content: https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000176873

As well as an article about deleting items from Files: https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000198685

To answer your questions generally:

- You use a report or data loader to produce a CSV file with the item IDs that you want to delete (from `Content` or `FeedItem`)
- You use the CSV as the source file with DataLoader and you can delete the records in bulk